# How to Count Textual Matches between Adjacent Cells in Excel?

Tags: excel

[image]

i want to know and calculate how many times two cells that contain text are adjacent in a table or range As shown in the attached picture

i want to know and calculate how many times two cells that contain text are adjacent

Comment: I see no image in your question. I suggest you upload your screencap to http://imgur.com and link to it. That said SUMPRODUCT may do what you want

Comment: Is it always those two particular strings?

Comment: no any two cells that are adjascent and contain the same text

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CountPairs()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim count As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    count = 0
    
    ' Iterate over PARTIE
    For i = 1 To 5 Step 2
        Set rng = ws.UsedRange.Columns(i).Resize(, 2)
        
        ' Iterate each row
        For j = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
            If rng.Cells(j, 1).Value = "awq" And rng.Cells(j, 2).Value = "plkjn" Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    MsgBox "The pair 'awq'; 'plkjn' appears " & count & " times."

End Sub
```